# DartEditor 1.4.3 new install

Tags: dart, dart-editor

i loaded on a fresh version of dart 1.4.3. When i tried to run my application in Dartium i get the following stacktrace and the application does not run. I don't know what this means.

my index.html file stacktrace in dart says \ Breaking on exception: ReferenceError: Platform is not defined

Thanks

```
**
 * @license
 * Copyright (c) 2014 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
 * This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
 * The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
 * The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
 * Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
 * subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
 */
// @version: 0.3.1-604ba08
window.PolymerGestures={},function(a){var b={shadow:function(a){return a?a.shadowRoot||a.webkitShadowRoot:void 0},canTarget:function(a){return a&&Boolean(a.elementFromPoint)},targetingShadow:function(a){var b=this.shadow(a);return this.canTarget(b)?b:void 0},olderShadow:function(a){var b=a.olderShadowRoot;if(!b){var c=a.querySelector("shadow");c&&(b=c.olderShadowRoot)}return b},allShadows:function(a){for(var b=[],c=this.shadow(a);c;)b.push(c),c=this.olderShadow(c);return b},searchRoot:function(a,b,c){if(a){var d,e,f=a.elementFromPoint(b,c);for(e=this.targetingShadow(f);e;){if(d=e.elementFromPoint(b,c)){var g=this.targetingShadow(d);return ...
```

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in polymer 0.11.0 +5.  You can use an older version of polymer and avoid the error.  In your pubspec.yaml file specify the version of polymer.  I used '>=0.10.0 <0.11.0'.